# What's the best way to upload data into Firestore before publishing app?

Tags: ios, database, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, import

I am building an app that uses Firestore as the database. Entering data directly into Firestore is very time-consuming and I already have much of my starting data in a json file.

How can I upload that json data into Firestore? Is there something I can run in Xcode to push that json data into Firestore?

I appreciate any help or guidance!

Comment: This tool worked great! https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has an [import/export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) feature, but that uses its own format. There is nothing built into Firestore for importing data from other JSON files.

Luckily Firestore has an API, so folks have built add-in solutions. A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+json+import) led me to this promising one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

Comment: Thank you! I will review the documentation as well as search for other third-party solutions.